# rails searchkick error: analyzer [searchkick_word_middle_index] not found for field [word_middle]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

After changing searchkick's configuration from `word_start` to `word_middle` an error appears only in test environment, with development mode everything works fine.

Error message:

```
[400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"analyzer [searchkick_word_middle_index] not found for field [word_middle]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: analyzer [searchkick_word_middle_index] not found for field [word_middle]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"analyzer [searchkick_word_middle_index] not found for field [word_middle]"}},"status":400}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found. I needed to create custom analyzer with name: 'searchkick_word_middle_index'.